# Print address of slice in golang

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, slice

I am very new on golang. Here I have one question confused me a while.
I know we should use "&" to get address, but what if we use printf on slice without "&"?

```
package main

import "fmt"

var slice = []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

func main() {

   fmt.Printf("address of slice %p \n", slice)

   fmt.Printf("address of slice %p \n", &slice)

}
```

The result is like this on my MacBook:

> address of slice **0x11354d0**
>
> address of slice **0x1128be0**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am no expert either but from what I understand from docs I think that if you use `%p slice`, it prints the address of 0th element (so maybe you can do some pointer arithmetic?!) and `%p &slice` prints the pointer of the slice including the "wrapper" or "overhead". I think you read the docs, I just want to make sure https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Comment: just tried! thank you so much :-)

Comment: "I am very new on golang" so two advices: The language is called "Go" and always read the full documentation of a function including the package level documentation. Always.

Comment: thank you, Volker!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Slices in Go are small, struct-like data structures, pointing to a backing array that actually holds the elements of the slice. Slice headers can be modeled with the type [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader):

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
```

Quoting from the package doc of `fmt`, the verb `%p`:

> ### Printing:
>
> #### The Verbs:
>
> Slice:
>
> ```
> %p    address of 0th element in base 16 notation, with leading 0x
> ```
>
> Pointer:
>
> ```
> %p    base 16 notation, with leading 0x
> The %b, %d, %o, %x and %X verbs also work with pointers,
> formatting the value exactly as if it were an integer.
> ```

So indeed, passing a slice value for the `%p` verb prints the address of the 0th element, which is the 0th element of the backing array, and when you pass `&slice` for `%p`, that will print the address of the slice header (because `&slice` is already a pointer value).

To verify, also print explicitly the address of the 0th element:

```
fmt.Printf("address of slice %p \n", slice)
fmt.Printf("address of slice %p \n", &slice)
fmt.Println(&slice[0])
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](http://address%20of%20slice%200x170460%20%20address%20of%20slice%200x17d0b8%20%200x170460)):

```
address of slice 0x170460 
address of slice 0x17d0b8 
0x170460
```

As you can see, `&slice[0]` is the same value as `%p` for `slice`.

Now let's modify the example to use our own backing array:

```
var arr = [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
var slice = arr[:]
```

So this way we can also print the address of the 0th element of the backing array:

```
fmt.Printf("address of slice %p \n", slice)
fmt.Printf("address of slice %p \n", &slice)
fmt.Println(&slice[0])
fmt.Printf("Array 0th: %p", &arr[0])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GS3T6ad1BjG)):

```
address of slice 0x170460 
address of slice 0x183e78 
0x170460
Array 0th: 0x170460
```

And yes, the address of the 0th element of the backing array is indeed the same as the address of the 0th element of the slice, which is the same value printed for `slice` when passed for the `%p` verb.

Comment: thank you so much! that's very clear. I should go to read document then :-)