# Parsing HTML with go-colly and function returns an empty slice

Tags: go, go-colly

I'm parsing a web site with the colly framework and something wrong is happening. I have a very basic function `getweeks()` to grab and return something, yet I'm getting an empty slice instead.

```
func getWeeks(c *colly.Collector) []string {
    var wks []string
    c.OnHTML("div.ltbluediv", func(div *colly.HTMLElement) {
        weekName := div.DOM.Find("span").Text()  // a string Week 1, Week 2 etc 
        wks = append(wks, weekName)  // weekName has actual value is not empty
        // If `wks` printed here it shows correctly how the slice gets populated on each iteration
    })
    return wks  // returns []
}

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
    )

    w := getWeeks(c)
    fmt.Println(w)  // []

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        r.Headers.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)")
    })

    c.Visit("target url")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: The slice header is updated inside `OnHTML` callback, but the value you print in `main` is the old slice header. You should work with `*[]string` instead.

---

First of all, the callback you pass to `c.OnHTML` will actually run only after you call `c.Visit`, so printing `w` right after `getWeeks`, would show an empty slice in any case.

However it would be an empty slice even by printing it after `c.Visit`, why?

A slice in Go is implemented as a data structure — called slice header (more info: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380391/print-address-of-slice-in-golang), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195834/how-to-inspect-slice-header)).

When you assign the return value of `getWeeks`, you're essentially copying the slice header, including its fields `Data`, `Len` and `Cap`. You can see it in [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0mi2_qLthn8) by printing the address of the slices with `%p` verb (using some other struct instead of go-colly to make the example self-contained):

```
func getWeeks(c *Foo) []string {
    var wks []string
    c.OnHTML("div.ltbluediv", func(text string) {
        weekName := text
        wks = append(wks, weekName)
    })
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &wks)
    return wks
}

func main() {
    c := &Foo{}

    w := getWeeks(c)

    c.Visit("target url")
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &w)

}
```

Prints two different memory addresses:

```
0xc0000ac030
0xc0000ac018
```

Now if you keep fishing around on Stack Overflow about slice and `append` behavior, you may find out that if the slice has sufficient capacity ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920534/why-does-append-modify-passed-slice), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042972/why-append-slice-in-go-change-the-original-slice), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697240/my-go-recursive-function-not-working-as-expected-due-to-slices)) the backing array is not reallocated.

However even if you do make sure the backing array is the same by initializing `wks` with sufficient capacity, the value of `w` is still a copy of the original slice header, therefore **with 0 length**. This is demonstrated in [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HWPSE3MypcZ), which prints:

```
in getWeeks reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0xc0000121b0, Len:0, Cap:3}
in callback reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0xc0000121b0, Len:1, Cap:3}
in callback reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0xc0000121b0, Len:2, Cap:3}
in callback reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0xc0000121b0, Len:3, Cap:3}
[]
in main reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0xc0000121b0, Len:0, Cap:3}
```

You could adjust the length of `w` by reslicing it ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HOIGYrYkrab)):

```
c.Visit("target url")
w = w[0:3]
fmt.Println(w) // [foo bar baz]
```

But this means that you need to know beforehand a reasonable capacity that doesn't cause reallocation, and the final length to reslice to.

Instead, return a pointer to a slice:

```
func getWeeks(c *colly.Collector) *[]string {
    wks := &[]string{}
    c.OnHTML("div.ltbluediv", func(div *colly.HTMLElement) {
        weekName := div.DOM.Find("span").Text()
        *wks = append(*wks, weekName) 
    })
    return wks
}
```

Or pass a pointer into `getWeeks`:

```
func getWeeks(c *colly.Collector, wks *[]string) {
    c.OnHTML("div.ltbluediv", func(div *colly.HTMLElement) {
        weekName := div.DOM.Find("span").Text()
        *wks = append(*wks, weekName)
    })
}
```

Fixed playground: https://go.dev/play/p/yhq8YYnkFsv